# Android: Handling image scaling and quality

Tags: android, image, graphics, icons, imageview

I am willing to accept a compromise of the assumption of a screen that is 480x800.  I have a title image for my app that is 220x40.  The text is clear and sharp on my desktop display.

The tutorials I have seen show adding images to an Android app by using auto-scalers like Eclipse's Icon Set wizard and defining a launcher icon set, or action button set, etc.  This tool auto-scales for hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi, etc.

When I create my ImageView and place it in my app, it stops looking like decently sized text that is easy to read, and now appears tiny in my emulator.  When I try to make it bigger by stretching it, the image quality shows to be garbage.  This suggests to me the scaling process has dropped the resolution of the image significantly.

What is the standard process for this?  How does one add an image to their app and have it maintain quality since the icon-wizard + fill_width + fill_height results in an ugly-as-sin result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the emulator that you are running having low resolution? Choose an emulator having higher resolution and put the image in hdpi or xhdpi folder...

Comment: Running a standard 3.7" 800x480 display.  I set up a tablet 7" Nexus hoping for a better result.  The icons were still tiny...

Comment: is the image in xhdpi or hdpi folder?

Comment: Eclipse's Icon Set scales the image and places it in hdpi, ldpi, and xhdpi